# Jenkins pipeline zip function expecting }

Tags: jenkins, zip, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create .zip out of .Net build using

```
   steps{
               zip zipFile: 'test.zip', glob: "${env.SOLUTION_DIR}\\folder1\\bin\\*.*" 
          }
```

Error shown is

```
12:25:36  WorkflowScript: 230: expecting '}', found ',' @ line 230, column 117.
12:25:36     test.zip', glob:��"
12:25:36              ^
```

Comment: This is likely due to an unclosed bracket elsewhere in your code.